CommonApi cmake error: source directory does not exist while using different toolchain
I'm a beginner of camke and trying to use CommonApi on my platfrom
I followed the tutorial : https://github.com/COVESA/capicxx-dbus-tools/wiki/CommonAPI-C---D-Bus-in-10-minutes
git clone https://github.com/GENIVI/capicxx-core-runtime.git
cd capicxx-core-runtime
cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install_folder .
cmake --build build/ --target install

I first compiled capicxx-core-runtime with a toolchain, it works fine.
when I change to another toolchain, build folder is not generated. "-Bbuild" is not working!
but build files(ex: makefile) are written into the project's root path.
and I got the error:
CMake Error: The source directory "capicxx-core-runtime/install" does not exist.

what make me confused is that in the compile pass case, there's no install directory, neither...
Is there anyone can give me a hint? where should I getting start to debug this compile error?
thanks
I tried to compare the environment variables after sourcing these two toolchains , but not got a clue.
And I compared OK/NG compile logs. But didn't find anything useful.

Which CMake version do you use? (cmake --version)

Is that the full output from cmake?

Cannot repro, seems to work normally for me. Although the canonical way of working with CMake would be: git clone xxx cd xxx mkdir build cd build cmake ../ make sudo make install - leaving all settings to default values.

cmake version 3.22.3

I rollbacked CommonApi version to (3.1.10) , and it build passed...  still don't know what happened though...
